# How to send data from react editor to server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create an editor to update my backend data but I am stuck at sending data from client to backend

Here is my following front-end code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { convertToRaw, EditorState, getDefaultKeyBinding } from "draft-js";
import draftToHtml from "draftjs-to-html";

const Editor = dynamic(
  () => import("react-draft-wysiwyg").then((mod) => mod.Editor),
  { ssr: false }
);

const Missions = ({ teamData, editable }) => {
  const { title, mission, teamId } = teamData;
  const classes = useStyle();
  const [missionContent, setMissionContent] = useState(mission);
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const [editorState, updateEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());

  const onEditorStateChange = (editData) => {
    updateEditorState(editData);
  };

  const handleSave = async () => {
    const selection = editorState.getSelection();
    const key = selection.getAnchorKey();
    const content = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const block = content.getBlockForKey(key);
    const type = block.getType();
    if (type !== "unordered-list-item" && type !== "ordered-list-item") {
      if (
        editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText("").trim().length !== 0
      ) {
        const content = editorState?.getCurrentContent();
        let html = await draftToHtml(convertToRaw(content));
        await updateEditorState(EditorState.createEmpty(""));
        setMissionContent(html.trim());
      }
    }
    setEditing(false);
  };

 return (
     <div className="team-mission-editor-container">
        <Editor
          wrapperClassName={"mission-editor-wapper"}
          toolbarClassName={"mission-editor-toolbar"}
          editorClassName={"mission-editor-editor"}
          editorState={editorState}
          onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
          toolbar={{...}}
         />
       )
```

Here is my back-end router:

```
router.put(
  "/team/:teamId",
  restrictedRoute,
  checkData,
  catchErrors(checkTeamPermissions),
  catchErrors(updateTeamData)
);
```

and here is my update function from backend:

```
exports.updateTeamData = async (req, res) => {
  // Get userId
  const userId = req.session.passport.user.id;
  // Get teamId
  const publicTeamId = req.params.teamId;

  // Fetch private id for team
  const teamId = await getTeamId(publicTeamId);

  // The user making the request
  const userPublicId = req.session.passport.user.publicId;

  // The creator of the team
  const creatorPublicId = req.body.creator;

  // Check who is making the request
  if (userPublicId !== creatorPublicId) {
    res.status(401).json("msg: You cant update a team you did not create");
  }

  // Updates
  const payload = {
    title: req.body.title,
    mission: req.body.mission,
    inputs: req.body.inputs,
    outputs: req.body.outputs,
    duration_in_months: req.body.duration_in_months,
    status: req.body.status,
    mergedTo: teamId,
  };

  // Update team data
  await models.Team.update(payload, {
    where: {
      id: teamId,
      creatorId: userId,
    },
  });

  res.status(200).json("msg: Updated team successfully");
};
```

How can I send data fromo my editor to backend and update it?

Thank you so much for helping me

Comment: just make an http post call inside `handleSave ` no?

Comment: @Nico    `const res = await axios.put(`/api/v1/teams/team/${teamData.public_team_id}`, content);` like this ?

Comment: yes, also if you use next.js you dont need axios :)

Comment: @Nico it still didn't send the data to my backend